# TSQL - Geography: Which polygon?

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography

Using SQL Server, when I get a result of 1 for the expression `@multipolygon.STIntersects(@points)`, indicating that the point is within one of the polygons comprising the multi-polygon

is there a way of finding out which polygon inside the many within the multi-polygon actually contains the point?

Comment: A multi-polygon is *one* feature, just like the number 3 is one feature. Besides, the only thing that identifies one polygon from the next is the index in the original specification. How would you identify any of the polygons yourself? If they *are* identifiable, they should probably be stored in different fields or rows, just as an order's items should be stored in separate `OrderItem` rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used something like this before:

```
select *
from dbo.Numbers as n
where @point.STIntersects(@multipolygon.STGeometryN(n.Number)) = 1
   and n.Number <= @multipolygon.STNumGeometries();
```

Where `dbo.Numbers` is a tally table. This query will return a 1-based index of which polygon(s) matched. If you want the polygons themselves as well, add `STGeometry(n.Number)` to the select list.

Comment: Thanks. @multipolygon.STGeometry(n.Number) should be @multipolygon.STGeometryN(n.Number); it appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the single multi-polygon row into many, single-polygon rows in a query and then doing the intersect, that will return only matching rows.

I haven't done anything like that myself, but this link might help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d99cef8e-d345-44ee-87e1-f9d4df851c35/multipolygon-results-split-into-polygons?forum=sqlspatial